# parsing a file with python "'str' object has no attribute 'get'"

Tags: python, arrays

I am a fairly new dev and trying to parse "id"  values from this file. Running into the issue below.

My python code:

```
import ast
from pathlib import Path

file = Path.home() /'AppData'/'Roaming'/'user-preferences-prod'

with open(file, 'r') as f:
    contents = f.read()
    ids = ast.literal_eval(contents)
profileids = []
for data in ids:
    test= data.get('id')
    profileids.append(test)
print(profileids))
```

This returns the error: ValueError: malformed node or string: <_ast.Name object at 0x0000023D8DA4D2E8> at ids = ast.literal_eval(contents)

A snippet of the content in my file of interest:

```
{"settings":{"defaults":{"value1":,"value2":,"value3":null,"value4":null,"proxyid":null,"sites":{},"sizes":[],"value5":false},"value6":true,"value11":,"user":{"value9":"","value8": ,"value7":"","value10":""},"webhook":"},'profiles':[{'billing': {'address1': '', 'address2': '', 'city': '', 'country': 'United States', 'firstName': '', 'lastName': '', 'phone': '', 'postalCode': '', 'province': '', 'usesBillingInformation': False}, 'createdAt': 123231231213212, 'id': '23123123123213, 'name': ''
```

I need this code to be looped as there are multiple id values that I am interested in and need them all to be entered into a list.Hopefully I explained it all. the file type is "file" according to windows, I just view its contents with notepad.

Comment: The data you provided is not valid JSON

Comment: Notepad should be enough to show that that is not a valid python literal so `ast.literal_eval` can't understand it.

Comment: @jferard I reverted you  changes because you changed the data. Hopefully the OP know what is in their file better than us.

Comment: @Goyo you're were right.

Comment: I don't think there is any hopes of parsing that data since it doesn't seem to conform to any specific format. I think your best bet is going to the source of the data and asking them to provide it in a coherent format.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to me that you have a file with a string representation of a `dict` (dictionary). So, what you need to do is:

> **`string_of_dict`**  →**`ast.literal_eval()`**→  **`dict`**

1. Open file and read in the text into a string variable. Currently I think this string is going into `ids`.
2. Then convert the string representation of `dict` into a `dict` using `ast` library as shown below. [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/988228/convert-a-string-representation-of-a-dictionary-to-a-dictionary)

```py
import ast
string_of_dict = "{'muffin' : 'lolz', 'foo' : 'kitty'}"
ast.literal_eval(string_of_dict)
```

**Output**:

```
{'muffin': 'lolz', 'foo': 'kitty'}
```

### Solution

Something like this should most likely work. You may have to tweak it a little bit.

```py
import ast

with open(file, 'r') as f:
    contents = f.read()
ids = ast.literal_eval(contents)
profileids = []
for data in ids:
    test= data.get('id')
    profileids.append(test)
print(profileids)
```

Comment: Thanks! This returns this error tho: ValueError: malformed node or string: <_ast.Name object at 0x000001ADCC357550>

Comment: Also share some part of your file so we could figure out if it is a formatted as a dict or something else. You would need to share from the beginning of your file.

Comment: Have adjusted the initial post with your requested info. though i replaced the real key name and removed the values for security.